# Populating a child router-outlet Angular2 not working

Tags: angular2-routing, angular2-template, angular2-directives

The solution below was the first attempt as below.

1. Created app.module.ts and app.route.ts.
2. Created default   for app.component.ts. The app.component router is working as expected so far for the first level routing.
3. Created a new module called Dashboard, with dashboard.module.ts and dashboard.routes.ts.
4. I imported the dashboard into the app.module.ts.
5. Created Sitebar,Header, and HeaderNav in the Dashboard.component.ts with child . But, no idea why the child navigation always shows in the first level router-outlet, instead of the child router-outlet.

Dashboard.component.ts code below.

```
    <div class="wrapper">
  <app-mydash-sidebar
    [headerText]="'No Rush'"
    [headerLink]="'http://www.bit-numbers.com'"
    [headerLogoImg]="'/assets/img/angular2-logo-white.png'"
    [backgroundColor]="'red'"
    [backgroundImg]="'/assets/img/sidebar-5.jpg'"
    [navItems]="navItems">
  </app-mydash-sidebar>

  <div class="main-panel">
    <app-mydash-navbar [navItems]="navItems"></app-mydash-navbar>

    <router-outlet ></router-outlet>
  </div>

</div>
```

app.component.ts below.

```
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Any idea?

***app.routes.ts***

```
import { ModuleWithProviders } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { LoginComponent } from './login/login.component';
import { MembersComponent } from './members/members.component';
import { AuthGuard } from './auth.service';
import { SignupComponent } from './signup/signup.component';
import { EmailComponent } from './email/email.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { BookingsComponent } from './bookings/bookings.component';
export const router: Routes = [
    { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
    { path: 'signup', component: SignupComponent },
    { path: 'login-email', component: EmailComponent },
    { path: 'members', component: MembersComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
    { path: '', component: LoginComponent},
    { path: 'bookings', component: BookingsComponent },
];

export const routes: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forRoot(router);
```

***mydash.routes.ts***

```
import { ModuleWithProviders } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { AuthGuard } from '../auth.service';
import { MydashBookingsComponent } from '../mydash/mydash-bookings/mydash-bookings.component';
import { MydashChartComponent } from '../mydash/mydash-chart/mydash-chart.component';
import { MydashDashboardComponent } from '../mydash-dashboard/mydash-dashboard.component';
export const Dashboardrouter: Routes = [
{
    path: 'dashboard',
    children: [{
        path: '',
        pathMatch: 'full',
        component: MydashDashboardComponent
    },
    {
        path: 'mybookings',
        component: MydashBookingsComponent
    }]
}
];
export const DashboardRouting: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forChild(Dashboardrouter);
```

***app.module.ts***

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { AngularFireModule } from 'angularfire2';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { LoginComponent } from './login/login.component';
import { EmailComponent } from './email/email.component';
import { SignupComponent } from './signup/signup.component';
import { MembersComponent } from './members/members.component';
import { AuthGuard } from './auth.service';
import { routes } from './app.routes';
import { IconsComponent } from './icons/icons.component';
import { NotificationsComponent } from './notifications/notifications.component';
import { UserComponent } from './user/user.component';
import { MydashModule } from './mydash/mydash.module';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { BookingsComponent } from './bookings/bookings.component';
import {FirebaseServiceService} from './services/firebase-service.service';


// Must export the config
export const firebaseConfig = {
   ...
};

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    LoginComponent,
    EmailComponent,
    SignupComponent,
    MembersComponent,
    IconsComponent,
    NotificationsComponent,
    UserComponent,
    HomeComponent,
    BookingsComponent,

  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(firebaseConfig),
     MydashModule,
    routes,

  ],
  providers: [AuthGuard,FirebaseServiceService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],

})
export class AppModule { }
```

***mydash.module.ts***

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

import { MydashChartComponent } from './mydash-chart/mydash-chart.component';
import { MydashCheckboxComponent } from './mydash-checkbox/mydash-checkbox.component';
import { MydashCloseLayerComponent } from './mydash-close-layer/mydash-close-layer.component';
import { MydashFooterComponent } from './mydash-footer/mydash-footer.component';
import { MydashNavbarComponent } from './mydash-navbar/mydash-navbar.component';
import { MydashSidebarComponent } from './mydash-sidebar/mydash-sidebar.component';
import { MydashSidebarItemsComponent } from './mydash-sidebar-items/mydash-sidebar-items.component';
import { MydashTableComponent } from './mydash-table/mydash-table.component';
import { MydashTaskListComponent } from './mydash-task-list/mydash-task-list.component';
import { MydashUserProfileComponent } from './mydash-user-profile/mydash-user-profile.component';
import { MydashNavbarItemsComponent } from './mydash-navbar-items/mydash-navbar-items.component';
import { MydashBookingsComponent } from './mydash-bookings/mydash-bookings.component';
import { DashboardRouting} from './mydash.routes';
import { MydashDashboardComponent } from '../mydash-dashboard/mydash-dashboard.component';
export interface DropdownLink {
  title: string;
  routerLink?: string;
}

export enum NavItemType {
  Sidebar = 1, // Only ever shown on sidebar
  NavbarLeft = 2, // Left-aligned icon-only link on navbar in desktop mode, shown above sidebar items on collapsed sidebar in mobile mode
  NavbarRight = 3 // Right-aligned link on navbar in desktop mode, shown above sidebar items on collapsed sidebar in mobile mode
}

export interface NavItem {
  type: NavItemType;
  title: string;
  routerLink?: string;
  iconClass?: string;
  numNotifications?: number;
  dropdownItems?: (DropdownLink | 'separator')[];
}
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    DashboardRouting,
  ],
  declarations: [
  MydashChartComponent,
  MydashCheckboxComponent,
  MydashCloseLayerComponent,
  MydashFooterComponent,
  MydashNavbarComponent,
  MydashSidebarComponent,
  MydashSidebarItemsComponent,
  MydashTableComponent,
  MydashTaskListComponent,
  MydashUserProfileComponent,
  MydashNavbarItemsComponent,
  MydashBookingsComponent,
  MydashDashboardComponent],

// These components are to export to allow access from the Dashboard. Do it manually, not done by ng CLI.
   exports: [
    MydashSidebarComponent,
    MydashNavbarComponent,
    MydashFooterComponent,
    MydashChartComponent,
    MydashTaskListComponent,
    MydashTableComponent,
    MydashUserProfileComponent,
    MydashCloseLayerComponent,
    MydashBookingsComponent
  ],
  providers:[]
})
export class MydashModule { }
```

Comment: Show your routing config. You probably haven't added the child routes as a child so it'll always load in the top router outlet.

Comment: @Chrillewoodz- Here you go my routes code. app.routes.ts

.. import the appropriates components above
export const router: Routes = [
    { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
    { path: 'signup', component: SignupComponent },
    { path: 'login-email', component: EmailComponent },
    { path: 'members', component: MembersComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
    { path: '', component: LoginComponent},
 { path: 'bookings', component: BookingsComponent },
];

export const routes: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forRoot(router);

Comment: Sorry, @Chrillewoodz . Could you please show me how to place my code here in an appropriate format? I tried to find the code tag, but I couldn't find it.

Comment: @Chrillewoodz- This is the Dashboard.routes.ts as a child route.
export const Dashboardrouter: Routes = [
{
    path: 'dashboard',
    children: [{
        path: '',
        pathMatch: 'full',
        component: MydashDashboardComponent
    },
    {
        path: 'mybookings',
        component: MydashBookingsComponent
    }]
}
];
export const DashboardRouting: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forChild(Dashboardrouter);

Comment: You can add it to the question instead so it's easier to read.

Comment: @Chrillewoodz- I have posted my source code here above.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the issue. The problem was because the dashboard component was missing in the file name **mydash.routes.ts**. I assigned the appropriate component underneath the path: 'dashboard', before the Child routes. Now, it works like a champ. Cheers! 
The Answer code below.

```
path: 'dashboard',
    component: MydashDashboardComponent,
    children: [{
```